# Relacionamento com 3 tabelas em laravel

Tags: laravel, relacionamento

Estou tentando fazer o relacionamento entre 3 tabelas no laravel. Com 2 tabelas eu consegui, graças a ajuda do fórum, mas não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar com 3 tabelas. o relacionamento é o seguinte:
Tenho 3 tabelas:

Noticias, Fotos e Unidade (unidades escolares)

```
tabela noticia -> id_noticias

tabela fotos-> id_fotos e id_noticias

tabela noticia_unidade
```

O relacionamento noticias com fotos está ok: na página principal aparecem 2 noticias e uma foto de cada. Agora preciso que seja filtrado por unidade: Na página da faculdade aparecer apenas as noticias da unidade 2, por exemplo.

Seguem os Models e Controllers:

#### Controller

```
public function index(){
    $not_faculdade = Noticia::with(['foto' => function($query){
        $query->get()->first();
        }])
    ->with(['unidade' => function($query2){
            $query2->where('id_unidade','2')->get();
        }])
    ->orderBy('id_noticias','DESC')
    ->take(2)
    ->get();
    // dd($not_faculdade);
    return view('pages_faculdade.noticia')->with('not_faculdade',$not_faculdade);
}
```

#### Models

```
class Noticia extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'noticias';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_noticias';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $dates = ['data'];
    protected $fillable =[
            'texto',
            'titulo',
            'legenda',
            'pasta',
            'subtitulo',
            'evento',
            'titulo_evento'
    ]; 

    public function foto()
    {
        //return $this->hasMany(Foto::class); 
        return $this->hasMany('App\Foto','id_noticia','id_noticias'); 
    }

    public function unidade()
    {
        //return $this->hasMany(Foto::class); 
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Unidade','id_noticias','id_noticia'); 
    }    
}

class Unidade extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'noticia_unidade';
    //  protected $primaryKey = 'id_noticia, id_unidade';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $fillable = [
        'id_unidade',
        'id_noticia'
    ];

    public function noticias()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Noticia','id_noticias','id_noticia'); 
    }
}
```

#### View

```
@foreach ($not_faculdade as $key=> $not)
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="painel_foto"><img src={{asset('public/'.$not->foto[0]->endereco)}}></div>
            <h4>{{ $not->titulo }}</h4>
            <p align="justify">
                <a href="#" class="noticia">
                {{$texto = substr($not->texto,0,150)." ..."}}
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div> 
@endforeach
```

Como disse, as 2 noticias com a foto de "capa" aparecem normalmente, mas não funciona o filtro.
Se eu der um `dd($not_faculdade)`, é mostrado os relacionamento aparentemente certos!

O que poderia estar errado?

Segue relacionamento (fiz do jeito que pude pq não sei mexer com essas ferramentas)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
1 notícia possui várias fotos que pertencem a uma única notícia
1 notícia pode aparece em várias unidades e cada unidade pode conter várias notícias

Comment: O que acontece? Não está filtrando pela unidade de ID 2?

Comment: Não está! Retorna todas as noticias, sem filtro!

Comment: As relações não estão erradas? se poderia colocar na sua pergunta as 3 tabelas e seus relacionamentos (o diagrama dessas tres tabelas com relação seria suficientes)?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, tentei desenhar o diagrama, mas não sei usar as ferramentas para isso.

Comment: Legal o relacionamento é. Muitos.pra muitos entre unidade e notícias está errado os relacionamentos mas além disse o que pretende, trazer as noticias que???

Comment: Pretendo trazer as noticias referentes a cada unidade. Por exemplo: A faculdade é unidade 2, o colégio é unidade 3... então trazer na página da faculdade todas as noticias que são da unidade 2.... e estão aparecendo todas, sem filtro...

Comment: Entendi @GiselePassoni mas, eu vou colocar como deveria ser os relacionamentos para que isso funcione! ok?

Comment: Ok, @VirgilioNovic

Answer (score 1):

Existem problemas nos seus relacionamentos mediante configurações no `Model` de suas `classes`, então, vou propor um modelo minimo para que possa fazer no seu projeto, ***exemplo***:

***Diagrama:***

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Classes*** [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent)

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Noticia extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['titulo', 'texto'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_noticia';

    public function unidades()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Unidade::class,
            'noticia_unidade',
            'id_noticia',
            'id_unidade');
    }
    //para trazer todas as fotos
    public function fotos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Foto::class, 'id_noticias', 'id_noticia');
    }
    // para trazer 1 foto
    public function foto()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Foto::class, 'id_noticias', 'id_noticia');
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Unidade extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['titulo'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_unidade';

    public function noticias()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Noticia::class,
            'noticia_unidade',
            'id_unidade',
            'id_noticia');
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Foto extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id_noticias', 'foto'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_fotos';

    public function noticia()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Noticia::class, 'id_noticias', 'id_noticia');
    }
}
```

***Como usar?***

```
 App\Noticia::with('foto')
     ->whereHas('unidades', function($q){
         $q->where('noticia_unidade.id_unidade',2);
     })
     ->get();
```

***Resultado***

```
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#724
     all: [
       App\Noticia {#734
         id_noticia: 1,
         titulo: "Noticia 1",
         texto: "Texto 1",
         foto: App\Foto {#746
           id_fotos: 1,
           id_noticias: 1,
           foto: "foto/0001-1.jpg",
         },
       },
       App\Noticia {#716
         id_noticia: 2,
         titulo: "Noticia 2",
         texto: "Texto 2",
         foto: App\Foto {#747
           id_fotos: 2,
           id_noticias: 2,
           foto: "foto/0002-1.jpg",
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

***Explicação:*** na tabela a noticia de número 3 não faz parte da unidade 2 então não aparece. Outro ponto que na classe `Noticia` foi criado dois métodos `foto` e `fotos`, onde respectivamente traz apenas uma foto e o outro todas as fotos da base, isso é bom para otimizar as `SQL`.

---

***Observação:*** verifique todos os campos, nomes, `classes`, ***etc.***, isso pode causar erros pela falta de configuração ou configuração incorretas. Um outro ponto é que deveria ter utilizado a nomenclatura padrão, mas, sem problemas se não usar, só que nesse aspecto deve configurar, `model` por `model`.

Comment: Fiz da forma que me orientou e apareceu esse erro:
QueryException in Connection.php line 647: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'noticia_unidade' (SQL: select * from `noticias` where exists (select * from `noticia_unidade` inner join `noticia_unidade` on `noticia_unidade`.`id_unidade` = `noticia_unidade`.`id_unidade` where `noticias`.`id_noticias` = `noticia_unidade`.`id_noticia` and `noticia_unidade`.`id_unidade` = 2))

Comment: @GiselePassoni se não fez não, está fazendo a `SQL` errada é o que eu disse é alguma configuração faltando, é algo simples, porque ele não pode nesse caso fazer um inner join para si mesmo... Deve ser configuração no model! dá uma olhada e edite a sua questão e coloque o que mudou!

Comment: @GiselePassoni olha como seria a `SQL`: `"select * from `noticias` where exists (select * from `unidades` inner join `noticia_unidade` on `unidades`.`id_unidade` = `noticia_unidade`.`id_
unidade` where `noticias`.`id_noticia` = `noticia_unidade`.`id_noticia` and `noticia_unidade`.`id_unidade` = ?)"` gerada pelo meu exemplo!

Comment: Desculpe, estou tendo que aprender as pressas pra desenvolver o portal nosso... tudo isso eh novidade pra mim. 
Vou mexer aqui até conseguir uma solução!

Comment: @GiselePassoni não precisa pedir desculpas, mas, a comunidade gosta de ajudar ... é isso uma troca, o que você fez agora porque a tabela está fazendo a SQL errada e isso é configuração.! dá uma olhada nos models meus por favor e me fala! estou aqui posso te ajudar

Comment: Depois de quebrar a cabeça, procurando onde estava o erro, consegui fazer funcionar, mas tive que deixar o belongsTo ao invés do belongsToMany. Por algum motivo que não consegui descobrir o pq, ele não estava funcionando...

Comment: @GiselePassoni tem algo de muito estranho, bom eu segui o seu desenho, teria que fazer um pente fino para saber a realidade do seu projeto.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que assim não funcionará. Você pode usar o `whereHas` no lugar de `with`.

```
$not_faculdade = Noticia::with(['foto' => function($query){
    $query->get()->first();
}])
->whereHas('unidade', function($query2){
    $query2->where('id_unidade','2');
})
->orderBy('id_noticias','DESC')
->take(2)
->get();
```

Comment: Ok, vou tentar já! Já posto aqui se deu certo isso!

Comment: Está aparecendo essa mensagem de erro:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')'

E diz que é na linha que contém esse código:  ->whereHas('unidade' => function($query2){

Comment: @GiselePassoni tenta substituir essa linha por: `->whereHas('unidade', function($query2){`

Comment: @JuniorNunes, fiz isso e o erro sumiu, mas continua sem filtrar as noticias por unidade!